# include() function in PHP behaves differently on XAMPP update

Tags: php, path, include, xampp

My files structure are :

```
/ (Root)
|-- includes
|-- |-- global.php
|-- |-- config.php
|-- index.php
```

In my `index.php` file I wrote :

```
<?php
include "includes/global.php";
?>
```

and in `includes/global.php` I wrote :

```
<?php
include "config.php";
?>
```

the `global.php` in `index.php` will be include whitout any problem but `config.php` in `global.php` will not be include !

I use XAMPP and in my old version of XAMPP (version 1.7.3) I don't have any problem but today I installed new version of XAMPP (version 1.8.1) and I have this problem !

I should use absolute path for including `config.php` file in `global.php` but I don't want to use absolute path, I want to include like before, how can I do this ?

Comment: Do you have any error? Print it there.

Comment: I am also wondering y wd it not work if it was working for previous version

Comment: @sectus no I didn't get any error, but the `constant` and `variables` which defined in `config.php` is empty in `global.php`

Comment: @BirjuShah yes this work on my previous version of xampp and php (the php version was 5.3.1 and now is 5.4.7

Comment: @sectus Sorry I forgot to say, I use `require` for config not `include` and the strange is my program will continue and didn't stop (I use xDebug too)

Answer (score 1):

The path in `include` is always relative to the top-level script. So your second (nested) include will not resolve correctly.

A common workaround is to use:

```
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__)."/config.php";
?>
```

inside `includes/global.php`. This will make the path resolve correctly, no matter where the toplevel script is located.

Comment: thanks, but how my code work before on older version of PHP and XAMPP ?

Comment: There may have been some setting in php.ini, but this is not a clean solution: If you have more than one `config.php` in different directories, you might end up with suprises. The way above will resolve the toplevel-relative path into a file-relative path: Most likely this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, so is this common method and should I use this method every were I want include/require file ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path). You need to add "." to it.

Or you can define it in runtime.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '.');
```

Comment: thanks, my `include_path` in `php.ini` is: `include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"` but not work too!

Comment: @MajAfy, check it in runtime.

Comment: how can I check it in runtime (sorry if my question is stupid)

Comment: @MajAfy, try `var_dump(get_include_path())` or `phpinfo()`

Comment: the output of this command is : `string '.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;.' (length=21)`

Answer (score 0):

In

```
global.php,
```

write

```
include "includes/config.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but don't really want to use a workaround, so I tried a few things and discovered that the code I'm working on is written with old style php opening tag, i.e. `<?`

As soon as I changed it to `<?php` the includes worked.